# Close Element when clicking anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have an element on my page that is toggled on and off by clicking on a text link.   I also need the element to hide when a user clicks ANYWHERE on the page outside of the element itself - this is my jQuery code - can someone please show me what modifications to make to do what I need?

```
$(function() {
$("#header-translate ul li").click(function() {
    $("#header-translate li ul").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500); 
});
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [jQuery's `one` function](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is perfect for this.

```
$(function() {
    $("#header-translate ul li").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $toClose = $("#header-translate li ul")
        $toClose.slideToggle(500, function() {
            if($toClose.is(':visible')) {
                $('body').one('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $toClose.slideUp(500);
                });
            }
            else {
                $('body').unbind('click');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What this will do is assure that this click handler will only get executed once, and only when the element is shown.

Comment: when I click inside the element that is shown, instead of triggering a link to a page, it closes the element - how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add a `click()` handler to the `$('body')`, and also `event.stopPropagation()` to your element.

```
$(function() { 
  $("#header-translate ul li").click(function(e) {   // don't forget that 'e'
    $("#header-translate li ul").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);  
    e.stopPropagation(); // so this doesn't register as a body click
  });
  $("body").click(function(e) {
    $("#header-translate").hide();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that your click handler will get executed every time they click anywhere--not always the best behavior.  What you really should do is bind and unbind that body click handler only when it's needed, achieved easily through jQuery's `one`.  See my answer below. :)

Comment: I presumed that the element would be `show()`n again under unspecificed circumstances. If not, your approach would certainly be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check if

```
$(function()
{
    var elToHideSelector = "#header-translate li ul";

    $("body").click(function(e)
    {
        if ( ! $(e.target).is(elToHideSelector + ',' + elToHideSelector + ' *') )
        {
            $(elToHideSelector).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used this code:

```
    $(function() { 
  $("#header-translate ul li").click(function(e) {     
    $("#header-translate li ul").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);  
    e.stopPropagation(); // so this doesn't register as a body click
  });
  $("body").click(function(e) {
      if ($('#header-translate li ul').is(':visible')) { $("#header-translate li ul").hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);}
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a click handler to BODY tag that will slide the element up and add event.stopPropagation() to the element that opens the element in the first place so the click to open is not send to BODY.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to the document (since the event bubbles up, you can capture it in a parent element)

```
$(function() {
    $("#header-translate ul li").click(function() {
        $("#header-translate li ul").toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500); 
        $(document).one('click', function(){  
            $("#header-translate li ul").hide();
        });
    });
});
```